# STM32L4 LSE Stops oscillating on Vbat

Tags: crystal-reports, stm32

I'm currently having problem with RTC clock (LSE) on STM32L433.
When Vdd is supplied and rtc configured clock is working as expected.

As soon as i remove vdd (vbat provided by coin cell) lse crystal stops oscillating hence rtc problem but backup registers are preserved time is frozen for vdd off period.

What could be cause of the problem? is there any pwr register that i'm missing?

Thanks for response in advance.

RTC setup code (library for registers is libopencm3)

```
void rtc_setup(time_struct time, date_struct date)
{
    usart_puts("1\n");

    rtc_wkup_set = false;

    /* cause a backup domain reset to select the clock source for RTC */
    RCC_BDCR |= RCC_BDCR_BDRST;
    RCC_BDCR &= ~RCC_BDCR_BDRST;
    pwr_disable_backup_domain_write_protect();

    RCC_BDCR &= ~(RCC_BDCR_RTCSEL_MASK << RCC_BDCR_RTCSEL_SHIFT);
    RCC_BDCR |= RCC_BDCR_RTCEN | (RCC_BDCR_RTCSEL_LSE << RCC_BDCR_RTCSEL_SHIFT) | (RCC_BDCR_LSEDRV_SHIFT << RCC_BDCR_LSEDRV_HIGH) | RCC_BDCR_LSEON;

    //TODO: Add timeout for RTC FAIL
    while ((RCC_BDCR & RCC_BDCR_LSERDY) == 0)
        ;
    usart_puts("2\n");
    /* enable RTC */

    rtc_unlock();

    RTC_ISR |= RTC_ISR_INIT;

    while (!(RTC_ISR & RTC_ISR_INITF))
        ;

    RTC_CR &= ~(RTC_CR_FMT);

    RTC_DR = (uint32_t)date;
    RTC_TR = (uint32_t)time;

    RTC_ISR &= ~(RTC_ISR_INIT);

    usart_puts("3\n");

    rtc_lock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was short on one of the legs of stm due to flux residue.
Issue solved

Comment: IMO delete the question